# Vagrant timeout connection

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, setup-project, vagrant-provision

After setup of latest version of virtual box and vagrant, I tired to run a command "Vagrant up" and faced the timeout error

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'bento/ubuntu-16.04' version '201910.20.0' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 80 (guest) => 8080 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 8025 (guest) => 8025 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.

If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
```

My setup:

```
Vagrant 2.2.6
VirtualBox 6.0
OS Ubuntu 16.04
```

As per reasearch on google tried solution like add a timeout

```
config.vm.boot_timeout = 300
```

Or set GUI

```
config.vm.gui = false
```

Restart the machine and reload vagrant,

Still in same issue....

Comment: Maybe improve this further by add what you see in the console when you start the machine. Does the machine start okay? The virtualbox VM console. Not the terminal where you run Vagrant.

Can you login to the machine using VirtualBox console as vagrant?

Comment: Can't reproduce this with Vagrant 2.2.4, VirtualBox 5.2.8 and Ubuntu 18.04. Not sure if it necessary but did you install VirtualBox guest additions?

Comment: yes, the machine started properly, and i used multiple versions of virtual box and vagrant.
Nothing works!!!